# How can I get `apt-get update` to reflect error status in its exit code?

Tags: apt, updates, error-handling, aptitude

When running `sudo apt-get update -q`, sometimes I see things like

```
Err:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/redis-server/ubuntu precise/main i386 Packages
  Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.83), connection timed out
Err:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/redis-server/ubuntu precise/main Translation-en
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
```

or like

```
W: http://us-central1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

But `echo $?` tells me that `apt-get update -q` succeeded.  How can I get the error/warning status to be fatal, and make `apt-get update` fail with a non-zero exit code?

Comment: Hmmmm, if I run it with an error my `echo $?` returns `100`.  Without errors it returns `0`.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I was misreading the travis logs I was looking at... What about when there are warnings?

Comment: Look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175146/apt-get-update-exit-status in the answer there is a little script that could detect both W: and E:.  But when I did the `apt update -q` with just warnings, I got `0` on the `echo $?`.  But the script passed and got both errors and warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Terrance, this question is very close to that other question [apt-get update exit status](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175146/apt-get-update-exit-status/) (in Unix & Linux StackExchange).

FYI I've just posted there [another solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/462288/297058) that can also be combined with the `travis_retry` Travis CI command (which might be the intended use case of the OP):

```
exec {fd}>&2 # copy stderr to some unused fd
travis_retry bash -o pipefail -c "sudo apt-get update -y -q 2>&1 | tee /dev/fd/$fd | ( ! grep -q -e '^Err:' -e '^E:' )"
exec {fd}>&- # close file descriptor
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a bash script that check the command output :

```
if { apt-get update 2>&1 || echo E: update failed; } > result.txt; cat result.txt | grep -q '^[(W)|(E]:'; then
    echo error
else (
        if  cat result.txt | grep -q '^[(Get)]:'; then
            echo repaired
        else 
            echo success
        fi
    )
fi
```

Here, we check if a line start with E (**Err:** or **E:**, etc..) for errors or with W for warnings. Both return the status code **error**.

If there is no error and there is a **Get:**, it means that we update our repos. It returns the status code **repaired**.

And finally, if we havent encountered any of those, the script was a **success**.